# Upgrade RabbitMQ Software

Tags: rabbitmq

We are currently running RabbitMQ on our Windows server machine.

We want to switch to Linux server machine.

Our setup is on AWS.

We have already created a Linux machine and installed latest version of RabbitMQ in it.

Our client applications use IP to connect to RabbitMQ server. The linux server has an IP.

We would like to change the RabbitMQ server without any downtime. We have messages in Windows based RabbitMQ server and would like to move those messages as well.

What would be possible options in this scenario?

Is there a way to upgrade RabbitMQ software later without any downtime?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to proceed in such order:

1. Read and handle both servers on backend: old (Windows machine) and new (Linux machine) RabbitMQ server.
2. Toggle all the clients to write into **new** server only.
3. When queues in the **old** server are empty, **old** server will be no required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's far easier if you don't need to move messages from one server to another.
I'd suggest this:

- Run both servers in parallel
- Create a bunch of new consumers ( a copy of all current consumers ) and make them consume from Linux server. At this moment, Linux server has no load yet.
- Gradually switch producers from Windows to Linux server, monitoring the system.
- Once all producers are switched, wait for queues on Windows server to be drained by existing consumers.
- Once all queues are drained on Windows server, switch off Windows server's consumers.
- You are done, all your load is on Linux server now